# get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>

Tags: angular

After switching to Angular 5.2.3, and running `ng cli` with a linter rule of `"deprecation": true` i get the following error in many of my tests:

```
get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>
```

The line that complains is something like

```
fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService)
```

with `MyService` being a class used for dependency injection.

I am at a loss to guess what the new syntax is supposed to be, as

```
fixture.debugElement.injector.get<MyService>(MyService)
```

gives a compile error that `Argument of type 'typeof MyService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<MyService> | InjectionToken<MyService>'.`

What is the correct way to use the injector to avoid deprecation errors?

Edit: See answer below, for Angular9 update.

Edit: It seems to be related to MyService being an abstract class. If I use a non-abstract class, the `.get<T>(T)` syntax works.

Edit: Fix is apparently pending some PR work - https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/25222

Comment: please provide a code (including the decorators etc) for `MyService`

Comment: Would you try `fixture.debugElement.injector.get<MyService>(Type<MyService>)`

Comment: fixture.debugElement.injector.get<MyService>(MyService) should work. `Type` is constructor function. There should be no problems if MyService is a class. Make sure that imports are correct and so on.

Comment: @Nour that syntax makes the linter happy, but the compiler then complains that `error TS1005: '(' expected.`. Also VSCode says something like `cannot find 'Type'` if i dont explicitly import it from @angular/core, and `'[ts] Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1` if i do import it. However if i do import it, and ignore VSCode, and run the test, i get  `Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[anonymous]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[anonymous]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for anonymous!
`

Comment: @smnbbrv i have a base class with no decorators: `

export abstract class MyService { }
    ` which is then provided to a subclass that extends MyService, and has @Injectable() decorator.

Comment: @estus thanks for confirming that this should be the syntax. The code and test works fine when using the deprecated form of .get (i.e. without the <T> bit), and I have verified that all types in use are imported.

Answer (score 27):

A better you can try to convert your service as Type and then use injector like this:

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

fixture.debugElement.injector.get<MyService>(MyService as Type<MyService>)
```

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE: For Angular9, the syntax has changed to this:

`TestBed.inject<IDataService>(IDataService)`.

This also works for abstract classes.

In VSCode, you can fix most of your cases by this

```
FIND: TestBed.get\(([^\)]+)\) as .*;
REPLACE: TestBed.inject<$1>($1);
```

---

PRE Angular 9.
So, it seems to be related to Abstract vs non-abstract classes.

I have posted my findings here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22063 in case someone runs into the same issue.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your findings here, so we can have a worthy (i.e. not link-only) answer to upvote and hence use as a basis for marking [other such threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818998/angular-5-appinjector-get-is-deprecated-use-typet-or-injectiontokent) as duplicates. But then, saying that, they just told you to ask on SO... so we'll get kinda stuck in a loop there!

Answer (score 7):

As a temporary fix you can try following:

`fixture.debugElement.injector.get<MyService>(MyService as any)`

Answer (score 6):

I've worked around this by defining an injection token:

```
export const DATA_SERVICE = new InjectionToken('DataService');
```

and using it to alias my service in the module:

```
...
providers = [
    { provide: DataService, useFactory: dataServiceFactory },
    { provide: DATA_SERVICE, useExisting: DataService }
]
...
```

I can then retrieve this service directly from an `Injector` using the injection token, without getting the deprecation warning:

```
this.dataService = injector.get(DATA_SERVICE);
```

In my case, `DataService` is an abstract class and I have two concrete 
(`@Injectable`) implementations to switch between mock data and real web service data. The appropriate version is instantiated in the `dataServiceFactory` method.

There are two overloads to the `injector.get()` call and I think that without the `InjectionToken` the deprecated overload is being called because the type system isn't recognising `typeof DataService` as an `InjectionToken`.

Interestingly, all injections of this service to components via constructors, such as:

```
constructor(
    ds: DataService
) { }
```

currently work. Will they work when the deprecated `get()` overload is removed in the future?

I think this is a question for the Angular team.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this linter warning even though I changed the code to match the non-deprecated get(). After upgrading the Angular CLI from 6.0.0. to 6.2.6 the warning went away.