# AppInjector get is deprecated, use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T>

Tags: angular, angular5, tslint

I am trying to get rid of this tslint warning:

> WARNING: get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type or
>   InjectionToken

The way I have my code setup is like this:

app.injector.ts

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export let AppInjector: Injector;

export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { setAppInjector } from './app-injector';
...

export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
        setAppInjector(injector);
    }
}
```

somecomponent.component.ts

```
...
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppInjector } from '../../app-injector';
...

export class SomeComponent {
    private router = AppInjector.get(Router);

    constructor() { /* code here */ }
}
```

I can't do `private router: Router` inside the constructor of `somecomponent.component.ts`, which is why I'm doing it like this (it is requirement, I can't change it).

So my main question is how can I change the line `private router = AppInjector.get(Router)` to get rid of the warning? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @underscore_d "If I use a non-abstract class, the .get<T>(T) syntax works."

Comment: I tried `AppInjecter.get<Router>(Router)` and I got the same error.

Comment: You shouldn't get it after that. The reason is because that error shows up because the `get(...)` version has the jsdoc comment that is causing you to see that: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0cb4f12a7a57087ec4e8329a04d5dfc430764b45/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L75-L79

Comment: Like mentionned, `AppInjector.get<Router>(Router)` should work Are you using `ng serve` or webpack's watch feature?  If so, try stoppping and restarting the server. I had a similar problem yesterday with `EventEmitter<T>`. After getting the syntax wrong once, it only worked with correct syntax **after** restart

Comment: Not sure what is wrong then. I restarted the server and and my IDE with the same warning. Maybe I'll just turn off the warning in tslint (not what I want to do though :( ).

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660938/get-is-deprecated-from-v4-0-0-use-typet-or-injectiontokent